# Let escape == cancel

Tags: feature-request, comments

Since <kbd>Enter</kbd> posts a comment, it would be nice to be able to hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> to abandon a comment or editing it.

Comment: Funny how this got the same six downvotes the dupe has without the upvotes :-7

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I would oppose this design.

The <kbd>Enter</kbd> key action is **non-destructive**. You can inadvertently press this key, and the worst that happens is that you submit a comment. For the first 5 minutes, comments can be edited if you submitted prematurely, and they can always be deleted if you change your mind.

The <kbd>Esc</kbd> key action, on the other hand, would be **destructive**. If you hit it accidentally, you would lose all of your work. Too risky, and for what advantage? How often do you really need to clear out the comment box and start all over? And for those rare cases, why doesn't <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>Del</kbd> work sufficiently well?

It's like why [you don't need a Clear/Reset button for web forms](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/42773).

I guess you could add a confirmation dialog, but then you've got another usability problem.

Comment: Ah, good point there, we sure don't want to end up with an "Undo reset" request afterwards... Great link btw

Comment: The destructiveness of the action could easily be alleviated, though - for example by storing the comment stub for the current page, and showing it if I click "add comment" again